# ¿Por qué no tiene efecto alguno el atributo value en ambos checkbox de este código?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Mi intención es **crear un *checkbox*** el cual, sin necesidad de agregarle un *label*, esté **acompañado de un texto que lo describa**. Por ello he decidido emplear el **atributo *value*** de los *input*. El **código** es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>StackOverFlow</title>
        
        <style type="text/css">
        
            *{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #botones{
                margin: 10px auto;
                padding: 5px;
                width: 50%;
                border: 2px solid black;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-around;
            }

            #pares, #impares{
                font-weight: bold;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            #enlaces_de_prueba a{
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                display: block;
            }

            .impares{
                color: chocolate;
                margin-left: 20px; /*No se aplicará por la preferencia de estilos*/
                border-bottom: dashed black 2px;
            }

            .pares{
                color: greenyellow;
                font-weight: bold;
                border-bottom: dashed black 2px;
            }
        
        </style>

        <script src="C:\Users\DELL\Documents\VSC_Workspace\jquery.js"></script>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(
                function(){
                    document.getElementById("impares").addEventListener("click",destacarImpares,false);
                    document.getElementById("pares").addEventListener("click",destacarPares,false);
                }
            );

            function destacarImpares() {
                $("#enlaces_de_prueba a:nth-child(2n)").toggleClass("pares");
            }

            function destacarPares() {
                $("#enlaces_de_prueba a:nth-child(2n+1)").toggleClass("impares");
            }

        </script>


    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="botones">
            <!--No se muestran los value de ambos botones-->
            <input type="checkbox" id="pares" value="PARES">
            <input type="checkbox" id="impares" value="IMPARES">
        </div>

        <div id="enlaces_de_prueba">
            <a href="https://www.google.es/" target="_blank">Google</a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">YouTube</a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">Instagram</a>
            <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox" target="_blank">Gmail</a>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Los *value* de los *button* funcionan perfectamente, pero no es así con los *checbox*. ¿Alguien puede explicarme por qué?¿Cómo logro mi objetivo? Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el pseudo-elemento [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::after):

```css
input[type=checkbox]::after{ 
    content: attr(value); 
    margin-left: 20px; 
}

*{ 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#botones{
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

#pares, #impares{
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
        <div id="botones">
            <!--No se muestran los value de ambos botones-->
            <input type="checkbox" id="pares" value="PARES">
            <input type="checkbox" id="impares" value="IMPARES">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No funciona porque el atributo 'value' de los checkbox no se renderiza, solo da el valor inicial de ese checkbox, esto sirve en caso de querer enviar información al servidor. Sí no quieres hacerlo con label, la respuesta anterior da la mejor opción.